# How to open a random fragment in onCreate for activity?

Tags: android, random, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to open a random fragment in my framelayout when I start MainAcitivity.

Questions:

1. How do I convert the **random1** value to a fragment?
2. Is it difficult to "refresh" the view to get another randow fragment when pressing a button on the screen?

   ```
   public class Beginner extends ActionBarActivity {

   private SoundPool spool;
   public int soundID_R1;
   public int soundID_R5;
   public int soundID_R8;

   private Fragment_gehorINTbeginnerR1 intBegFragment_R1;
   private Fragment_gehorINTbeginnerR5 intBegFragment_R5;
   private Fragment_gehorINTbeginnerR8 intBegFragment_R8;
   private int randomFragmentNum;
   private FrameLayout container;
   private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.fragment_beginner);

       initUI();
   }

   private void initUI() {
       container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.beginner_frame);
       fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
       setRandomFragment();
   }

   private void setRandomFragment() {
       Random random = new Random();
       randomFragmentNum = random.nextInt(2);
       //random choose fragment
       switch (randomFragmentNum) {
           case 0: {
               intBegFragment_R1 = new Fragment_gehorINTbeginnerR1();
               fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.beginner_frame, intBegFragment_R1);
               fragmentTransaction.commit();
               break;
           }
           case 1: {
               intBegFragment_R5 = new Fragment_gehorINTbeginnerR5();
               fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.beginner_frame, intBegFragment_R5);
               fragmentTransaction.commit();
               break;
           }
           case 2: {
               intBegFragment_R8 = new Fragment_gehorINTbeginnerR8();
               fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.beginner_frame, intBegFragment_R8);
               fragmentTransaction.commit();
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in random: very small parameter for random choose between three fragment. This code help you. Please insert in setRandomFragment():

```
randomFragmentNum = random.nextInt(150);
        if (randomFragmentNum < 50) {
            randomFragmentNum = 0;
        } else if (randomFragmentNum < 100) {
            randomFragmentNum = 1;
        } else randomFragmentNum = 2;
```

UPDATE 2:
For five fragments

```
randomFragmentNum = random.nextInt(250);
            if (randomFragmentNum < 50) {
                randomFragmentNum = 0;
            } else if (randomFragmentNum < 100) {
                randomFragmentNum = 1;
            } else if (randomFragmentNum < 150) {
                randomFragmentNum = 2;
            } else if (randomFragmentNum < 200) {
                randomFragmentNum = 3;
            } else 
                randomFragmentNum = 4;
            }
```

Comment: I hope that help you
With best regards, Andrew Prayzner

Comment: Thank you very much! It works exactly as I want to! :D

Comment: Hmm... I don't understand how to make this code for more fragments, like 5?

Comment: What's problems?) You have algorithm for random choose fragment

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution (UPDATE 2). If use 2 random fragment you must set in random.getInt() value 100, if three fragment - 150, four - 200... And add blocks if-else for logic choose fragment:

```
 /**
     * Created by scijoker on 2/14/14.
     */
    public class TestRandomFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {
        private LoginFragment loginFragment;
        private SignUpFragment signUpFragment;
        private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.access_activity);

            initUI();
        }

        private void initUI() {
            fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().openTransaction();
            setRandomFragment();
        }

        private void setRandomFragment() {
            Random random = new Random();
           int randomFragmentNum = random.nextInt(100);
        if (randomFragmentNum < 50) {
            randomFragmentNum = 0;
        } else{
            randomFragmentNum = 1;
        }
            //random choose fragment
            switch (randomFragmentNum) {
                case 0: {
                    loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fl_container, loginFragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit()
                    break;
                }
                case 1: {
                    signUpFragment = new SignUpFragment();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fl_container, signUpFragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit()
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I can't get it to work because my class extends ActionBarAcitivity, intstead of FragmentActivity.

Comment: For use fragments in your activity your class must extends FragmentActivity

Comment: If you're using the v7 appcompat library, your activity should instead extend ActionBarActivity, which is a subclass of FragmentActivity (for more information, read Adding the Action Bar). (from Android Developers site)
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Comment: No more errors... but I always loads Fragment #1 (namned R1 in my code). Can you find the problem?

Comment: what number value you set in random.nextInt(1)?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example:

```
   switch(random1.nextInt(3)){
        case 0:  setMyFragment(new Fragment_gehorINTbeginnerR1());
                 break;
        case 1: setMyFragment(new Fragment_gehorINTbeginnerR5());
                break;
        case 2: setMyFragment(new Fragment_gehorINTbeginnerR8());
                break;
    }
```

I use a method to load my fragments:

```
 public void setMyFragment(Fragment fr){
    try{
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if(fr != null){
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.Mainfragment, fr, null);
                            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    }catch(IllegalStateException e) {           
        Log.e(TAG, "ISE setting main view "+e.getMessage());
    }       
}
```

Comment: setMyFragment in the switch gives me errors. I'm really new to coding, why does this happend?